# Building a KNN classifier with multiple classes that identifies different audio

Tags: matlab, audio

I am in the process of building a KNN algorithm with the purpose of identifying and categorizing common engine problems in Matlab. I have been using the builds from the book 'An Introduction To audio Analysis: A Matlab Approach' which contains exactly what I need to continue my experiment. The problem is that when I identify where the audio samples are kept on my computer, the system claims that it gives out the message "audio sample path is not valid!" Below is the original algorithm the authors of the book have supplied

function kNN_model_add_class(modelName, className, classPath, ...
    listOfStatistics, stWin, stStep, mtWin, mtStep)

```
%
% function kNN_model_add_class(modelName, className, classPath, ...
%         listOfStatistics, stWin, stStep, mtWin, mtStep)
%
% This function adds an audio class to the kNN classification model
% 
% ARGUMENTS;
% - modelName:  the filename of the model (mat file)
% - className:  the name of the audio class to be added to the model
% - classPath:  the path of the directory where the audio segments of the
%               new class are stored
% - listOfStatistics:   list of mid-term statistics (cell array)
% - stWin, stStep:      short-term window size and step
% - mtWin, mtStep:      mid-term window size and step
%
% Example:
% kNN_model_add_class('modelSpeech.mat', 'speech', './Music/', ...
%  {'mean','std',}, 0.050, 0.025, 2.0, 1.0);
%

if ~exist(classPath,'dir')
    error('Audio sample path is not valid!');
else
    classPath = [classPath filesep];
end

% check if the model elaready exists:
fp = fopen(modelName, 'r');
if fp>0 % check if file already exists
    load(modelName);
end

% Feature extraction:
D = dir([classPath '*.wav']);
F = [];
for (i=1:length(D)) % for each wav file in the given path:
    curFileName = [classPath D(i).name];
    FileNamesTemp{i} = curFileName;
    % mid-term feature extraction for each wav file:
    midFeatures = featureExtractionFile(curFileName, ...
        stWin, stStep, mtWin, mtStep, listOfStatistics);

    % long-term averaging:
    longFeatures = mean(midFeatures,2);       

    F = [F longFeatures];
end

% save the model:
Statistics = listOfStatistics;
fp = fopen(modelName, 'r');
if fp<0 % model does not exist --> generate     
    ClassNames{1} = className;
    Features{1} = F;   
    FileNames{1} = FileNamesTemp;
    save(modelName, 'ClassNames', 'Features', ...
        'Statistics', 'stWin', 'stStep', 'mtWin', 'mtStep', 'FileNames');
else
    load(modelName);
    ClassNames{end+1} = className;
    Features{end+1} = F;
    FileNames{end+1} = FileNamesTemp;
    save(modelName, 'ClassNames', 'Features', ...
        'Statistics', 'stWin', 'stStep', 'mtWin', 'mtStep', 'FileNames');
end
```

Here is the way that I have implemented it into my own project.

```
    %Knn algorithm training
%path to folder containing the audio segements 

strDir ='/Users/itsolutions/Documents/MATLAB/Wav_engine_edits ';

%mid-term statistics to be used:

Statistics = {'mean','median','std','stdbymean','max','min'};

%short-term and mid-term, processing windon length and step:

stWin = 0.040; stStep = 0.040;

mtWin = 2.0;  mtStep = 1.0;

%perform feature extraction
kNN_model_add_class ('model8.mat','connection rod noise', [ strDir '/Connection_rod_edits/'],Statistics, stWin, stStep, mtWin, mtStep);

kNN_model_add_class ('model8.mat','detonation noise', [strDir ' /Detonation_noise_edits/'],Statistics, stWin, stSteo, mtWin, mtStep)

%kNN_model_add_class ('model8.mat','Engine bearing noise' [strDir '/Engine Bearing Noise edits/'],Statistics, stWin, stStep, mtWin, mtStep);
```

Any ideas? I have looked into the objects present in the function knn_model_add_class() and have found that it is still using wavread, which in the 2016b version of matlab in invalid syntax now.

Could anyone give me a hand? Seems like I am going in circles and it is something really obvious that i can't see.

Regards

M.Brown

Edit:

Using the process of elimination I have found that the error comes from this piece of code

```
if ~exist(classPath,'dir')
error('Audio sample path is not valid!');
```

else
    classPath = [classPath filesep];
end

The code cannot seem to find the audio samples in question. I have contacted the author of the book, but until then does anybody know why the matlab file path won't recognize the wav files?

Comment: in strDir you have a space at the end. I assume that the space shouldn't be there. The same applies to your second call of the kNN_model_add_class function, you have a space in front of /Detonation_noise_edits

Comment: The space is present in the code in the book, and spaces don't usually make a difference in code unless declaring variables sometimes, but in this case it doesn't make a difference. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Well, your error is pretty obvious, your path to the audio samples are not valid, i.e. the dir to your audios are not valid. So check where your audio files are and run this line `D = dir([classPath '*.wav']);` until your can find your .wav file

Comment: That's what I thought it meant, but everything is in it's right place  from what I can see, and whenever I run`code`  D = dir([classPath '*.wav']);`code`  it gives the error that classPath is not a function/variable.

Comment: Just a thought: Would the fact that I am using folders containing the audio effect the way that matlab retrieves audio? I don't remember it being an issue last year, although that was only dealing with two classes rather than 6.

Comment: Just drag the audio file into your matlab environment.